# Remove keys from anywhere in a JSON string without deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

Without deserializing and reserializing the following deeply-nested JSON string (if this is possible), how to remove any key with the name "REMOVEME" from any nested level?

**Tried:**

Reluctantly tried deserializing to `JsonObject` / `LinkedHashMap` to traverse the structure with `node.remove(e.getKey())` on offending keys, but Gson throws concurrent modification exceptions, and Jackson requires full deserialization.

Before:

```
{
    "a": {
        "REMOVEME" : "unwanted",
        "b": {
            "REMOVEME" : "unwanted",
            "c": {
                "d": {
                    "REMOVEME" : "unwanted",
                    "something": "default",
                    "e": {
                        "f": {
                            "REMOVEME" : "unwanted",
                            "g": {
                                "REMOVEME" : "unwanted",        
                                "h": {
                                    ... ,
```

After:

```
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": {
                    "something": "default",
                    "e": {
                        "f": {
                            "g": {
                                "h": {
                                    ... ,
```

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: It’s impossible to delete an entry from a LinkedHashMap which is what I tried. Plus it requires deserialization. That code will not be relevant.

Comment: Try to use [JOLT](https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/#inception) transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is with streaming token-parsing with Gson. This method handles extremely large JSON strings with ease.

Example before and after:

```
{"a":{"removeme":"unwanted","b":{"c":{"removeme":{"x":1},"d":{"e":123}}}}}
{"a":{"b":{"c":{"d":{"e":123}}}}}
```

Essential test harness:

```
String rawJson = "{\"a\":{\"removeme\":\"unwanted\",\"b\":{\"c\":{\"removeme\":{\"x\":1},\"d\":{\"e\":123}}}}}";

final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonReader reader = gson.newJsonReader( new StringReader( rawJson ) );

StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
JsonWriter writer = gson.newJsonWriter( outWriter );

JsonStreamFilter.streamFilter( reader, writer, Arrays.asList( "removeme" ) );

System.out.println( rawJson );
System.out.println( outWriter.toString() );
```

Tokenizing and filtering magic:

```
public class JsonStreamFilter
{
    /**
     * Filter out all properties with names included in the `propertiesToRemove` list.
     * 
     * @param reader JsonReader to read in the JSON token
     * @param writer JsonWriter to accept modified JSON tokens
     * @param propertiesToRemove List of property names to remove
     * @throws IOException
     * @see Gson docs at https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming
     */
    public static void streamFilter(
        final JsonReader reader,
        final JsonWriter writer,
        final List<String> propertiesToRemove
    ) throws IOException
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            JsonToken token = reader.peek();
            switch ( token )
            {
                case BEGIN_ARRAY:
                    reader.beginArray();
                    writer.beginArray();
                    break;
                case END_ARRAY:
                    reader.endArray();
                    writer.endArray();
                    break;
                case BEGIN_OBJECT:
                    reader.beginObject();
                    writer.beginObject();
                    break;
                case END_OBJECT:
                    reader.endObject();
                    writer.endObject();
                    break;
                case NAME:
                    String name = reader.nextName();

                    // Skip all nested structures stemming from this property
                    if ( propertiesToRemove.contains( name ) )
                    {
                        reader.skipValue();
                        break;
                    }

                    writer.name( name );
                    break;
                case STRING:
                    String s = reader.nextString();
                    writer.value( s );
                    break;
                case NUMBER:
                    String n = reader.nextString();
                    writer.value( new BigDecimal( n ) );
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    boolean b = reader.nextBoolean();
                    writer.value( b );
                    break;
                case NULL:
                    reader.nextNull();
                    writer.nullValue();
                    break;
                case END_DOCUMENT:
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure the way you are trying to delete the property from node, but it is possible to delete the property i did it by using jackson

```
String json = "{\n" + 
            "    \"a\": {\n" + 
            "        \"REMOVEME\" : \"unwanted\",\n" + 
            "        \"b\": {\n" + 
            "            \"REMOVEME\" : \"unwanted\"\n" + 
            "        }\n" + 
            "    }\n" + 
            "}";

    JsonNode node = objectMapper.readTree(json);
    ObjectNode node1 = (ObjectNode) node.get("a");

    node1.remove("REMOVEME");
    System.out.println(node1);  // {"b":{"REMOVEME":"unwanted"}}
    System.out.println(node);   // {"a":{"b":{"REMOVEME":"unwanted"}}}
```

Comment: Hey, this is a nice turn of events. I've presently been working with Gson and its `LinkedHashMap`-backed `JsonObject`s which are immutable. Using Jackson and `readTree` I can recursively remove nodes. This solution still requires trans-serialization, but it is progress. Thx.

Comment: I'm holding out for a way to perform this string transformation "without deserializing and reserializing", possibly with a `JsonReader`-`JsonWriter` approach. The JSON strings are large.

Comment: It might be hard and definitely will not be in straight forward, what is the problem in deserializing into `JsonObject` and removing keys? @Drakes

Comment: Actually, I just solved it exactly with JSON streaming and it was ridiculously simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

If the exact value and name of the object is known, you can do a regex replace with nothing for it, ex:

```
jsonString.replaceAll("\"REMOVEME\" ?: ?\"unwanted\"[,}]","")
```

Otherwise if only the key is known, you can still match it with a slightly more complex expression:

```
\"REMOVEME\" ?: ?.+[,}]
```

Or, backwards if only the value is known.

```
\".+\" ?: ?\"unwanted\"[,}]
```

If all of them are dynamic, but you still have a list of them, you should be able to iterate through them, dynamically changing each key/value to ones that match.

Comment: Regex on the surface looks like an ideal solution, but values may contain escaped commas or braces, so in production we really, really try to avoid regex on JSON strings.

Comment: You can use regex to ensure that there are not an odd finite number of escapes before a character by using backtracing, As an example, here is a regex that matches arguments, using backtracing to make sure that any opens or closes are not escaped:
`(?<=^|(?<=^|[^\\\\])(?:\\\\\\\\){0,1000})([\"']|`(?:``))(?:|(.*?)(?<=[^\\\\])(?:\\\\\\\\)*)\\1|(\\S+)`

Comment: This is either genius or insanity.

Comment: the above regex is so alien it would take me 100 years to decode, hats off to the writer